# Restore .bak more than 10GB size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore

I have to restore a backup of a database SQL Server 2014

I am trying to restore it but it doesn't load the database. The .bak weighs 11GB and when I load the .bak shows that no backup copies was selected to restore it and don't appear nothing more and don't appear backup copies

I try to make a new database, make a table with some data and make a .bak of this and it restore me well. So, I don't know...

Why can be?

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say that it doesn't load the database, do you get any errors? Are you trying to restore the database over another, or to a new database? Are you using the GUI?

Comment: @scsimon No errors, only what I say. Over a new database. Yes, I use the GUI

Comment: Yeah so the restore completes? What do you mean it doesn’t load data

Comment: @scsimon Now I can restore but appears a message that the limit is 10240MB aprox 10GB and I want to restore a 11GB .bak file. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting that message, then you are trying to restore a database to a [SQL Server Express instance.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) SQL Server Express is a free version of SQL Server that doesn't have many features that paid version have. For example, it doesn't have SQL Agent. Another limitation, which is the one you are experiencing, is that you can only have databases up to 10GB in size. See more in the documentation attached.

If you aren't working with production data, then you can use [SQL Server Developer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions) and restore your database

Comment: Can I use SQL Server Developer with .bak file more than 10GB? Where I can download SQL Server 2014 Developer? I only find 2017 and my database is 2014

Comment: Yes, as i explained in my post. I would use 2017 since it's backwards compatible.